# 3 digits difference between Java Instant and Postgres TIMESTAMPTZ

Tags: java, postgresql, assertj, spring-data-jdbc

Given the following field in Java:

```java
private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();
```

corresponding to the following field in Postgres:

```sql
created_date TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and saved to database using Spring Data JDBC [CrudRepository save(S entity)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save(S)).

When checking for equality the original object field and the saved one with:

```java
assertThat(original_obj.getCreatedDate()).isEqualTo(database_obj.getCreatedDate());
```

I get the following mismatch:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
      expected: 2023-05-29T10:41:12.555839137Z
       but was: 2023-05-29T10:41:12.555839Z
```

It appears the `Instant` loaded from database has 3 less digits than the original Instant.

How can I make the two instants match? Why are they different?

Comment: I'd say use the same rule you would use for `double`: allow for a small delta in the comparison.

Comment: Before using a type in Java or Postgres, you should **read the documentation** to learn about its characteristics and its limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java Time stores time with up to 1 [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) precision, while Postgres stores [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

You can either allow delta in the comparison as suggested in the comments or.. an easier solution would be to just truncate the date in Java if you don't care about those nanos:

```java
Instant createdDate = Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like they round the same way

Comment: @nafg, I haven't seen situations when they differed. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer not to truncate the expected value, [`isCloseTo`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractTemporalAssert.html#isCloseTo(java.lang.String,org.assertj.core.data.TemporalOffset)) and [`byLessThan`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#byLessThan(long,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) could help:

```
assertThat(original_obj.getCreatedDate()).isCloseTo(database_obj.getCreatedDate(), byLessThan(1, ChronoUnit.MICROS));
```